# Magento 2 override template file using custom module

Tags: magento2, overrides

I need to override below template file using custom module

> Magento_ConfigurableProduct::product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I got answers after research. Hope it helps to someone.

Add below code in di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable" type="VendorName\Module\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable" />
</config>
```

create a Configurable.php at path "app/code/Tm/Stockinfo/Block/Product/Renderer/Configurable.php"and add below code.

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\Module\Block\Product\Renderer;

class Configurable extends \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable {
    protected function getRendererTemplate() {
      return $this->isProductHasSwatchAttribute ?
      self::SWATCH_RENDERER_TEMPLATE : 'VendorName_Module::product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml';
   }
}
```

Create template file "Configurable.phtml". at below location.

> app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

Answer (score 2):

**=> create file under :**

> app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.configurable">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Modulename::product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**=> Set your templae file at below location :**

> app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

**Clear cache.**

Comment: Thanks Rakesh for your answers. i applied this solution and its not override, please refer this link https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4400

Comment: try with above solutions in default.xml instead of catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml file